# How to use Wix Bootstrap and log parts of the bundle installed

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I'm setting up a Wix Bootstrapper installation that installs a number of prerequisites application components (most from Microsoft).  Many are x86 or x64 editions of software. Each of those parts will be installed in various default directories. Is it possible to generate a master log which includes all the fragment Exe/msi package installations in the final Software product target directory?
The MyBootstrappedApp.exe /log "Installation.log" does a nice job at a higher level. But I really wanted to ensure the users just click and install, but have the MyBootstrappedApp.exe automatically keep a verbose installation of it and all components. 
Is this a WIX/MSI limitation?

```
 <Chain>      
  <!--<PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx35_Package" />-->
  <!-- Software uses the excel automation code to read Excel data files. -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Ace12_Installation_x64_Package" />
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Ace12_Installation_x86_Package" />      
  <!-- Software reporting is based on SQL Server Reporting Services. -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id ="Microsoft_Reports_2010_Installation_Package" />
  <!-- To communicate with SQL Server, the MS Access components will require the SQL Server Native Client. -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id ="Microsoft_SQL_Server_2012_x64_Installation_Package" />
  <PackageGroupRef Id ="Microsoft_SQL_Server_2012_x86_Installation_Package" />      
  <MsiPackage Id="CadiSoftware_Package" DisplayName="CADI (Computer Aided Data Input) software" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" SourceFile="$(var.Cadi.Wix.TargetPath)" DisplayInternalUI='yes' />      
</Chain>
```

Here is a sample fragement of the Microsoft Sql Server 2012 x64 native driver installation

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">  
<Fragment Id="Microsoft_SQL_Server_2012_x64_Installation_Fragment">
<PackageGroup Id="Microsoft_SQL_Server_2012_x64_Installation_Package">
  <!--  Install the SQL Server 2012 Native Client drivers x64. -->
  <!--  DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409"-->
  <MsiPackage 
    Id="SQLClient2012_x64_Package" 
    Name="SQLClient2012_x64"
    DisplayName="Microsoft SQL Server Native Client drivers"
    SourceFile="Prerequisites\SqlNativeClient\x64\sqlncli.msi"
    InstallCondition="VersionNT >= v5.1 AND VersionNT64"        
    Compressed="yes" 
    Vital="yes"                         
    DisplayInternalUI="no"/>
</PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: To add on to Rob's answer, if you are writing a custom bootstrapper rather than using the standard WiX bootstrapper, you can see how to access those variables and copy the various log files in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741139/how-to-set-or-get-all-logs-in-a-custom-bootstrapper-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Burn engine does not "merge" log files today. You'll get a log file for the Bundle that can have references to the child log files and log files for each of the packages. However, the Burn engine does provide `Variables` that will provide the paths to all of the log files. You could then use those variables to create an uber-log file or a special report or whatever you'd like to present to the user.