# How to change the logs path in wix extended bootstrapper application

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

Can anyone let me know, how I can change the log path in wix standard Bootstraper application. By default logs are created in temp directory.

[How to set or get all logs in a custom bootstrapper application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741139/how-to-set-or-get-all-logs-in-a-custom-bootstrapper-application)

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-and-Msi-logging-revisited-td7578871.html

Above links say, at the end or when any error occurs, logs can be copied from tmp to different directory.

But I have to create the logs from the beginning in a different directory, rather than copying at the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use /log C:\Path\to\log\file.txt in the command line of your bootstrapper. If you want to change teh default location of the log you would need to modify your burn code and build using your own burn.exe which is a nightmare to maintain when you update wix or need to distribute your wix build process to another build system.

Comment: Thank you for the response Brian. I am using wix extended bootstrapper to bundle multiple msi. I would like to change the path from custom bootstrapped. Please let me know, if you have any idea about it. Thanks